# Working with optional arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, optional-parameters

I created a function like this:

```
window.SetUploader = function(action, elementID, multiple, allowedExtensions) {
    //Optional arguments
    if (actionUploader == null) {
      actionUploader = "/Upload";
    }
    if (elementIDUploader == null) {
      elementIDUploader = "file-uploader";
    }
    if (multipleUploader == null) {
      multipleUploader = false;
    }
    if (allowedExtensions == null) {
      allowedExtensions = [];
    }

    //Function
     .....
};
```

To call this function, use the following code:

```
SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Logo', { allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip'] });
```

Note the parameter `allowedExtensions`, it does not change the value.

Debugging function, `allowedExtensions` value is **null**.

**What is wrong?**

Comment: You are referring to a different variable name in your if test.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your actual `allowedExtendsions` parameter as the third argument which is where the `multiple` formal parameter appears.  Put `undefined` before it.

```
SetUploader(
   /* action */    '/Projects/ImageUpload', 
   /* elementId */ 'Logo', 
   // NEED VALUE FOR MULTIPLE HERE
   ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip'])
```

You are also never using the `action` parameter, instead checking and setting a global variable `actionUploader`.

Typically when allowing optional arguments you have one particular argument which is a map of extra arguments.

```
function (requiredParam, anotherRequiredParam, extra) {
  var optionalParam = extra ? extra.optionalParamName : defaultValue;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to ignore this value, let him take the default value defined in the function!

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa, so you want to ignore the value of a particular parameter and use one defined in the function regardless of what the caller passes in?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your object as third parameter (as multiple), your allowedExtensions is fourth.

Also you are checking variables with "Uploader" as name suffix. They are not variables that you pass.

Next, if you would pass  `{ allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip'] }` as fourth parameter to get hold of array with extensions you would have to write `allowedExtensions.allowedExtensions`

Answer (score 1):

First of all your variables are not null, they are undefined and you need to check with the `===` operator.
undefined and null are not the same, variables in JavaScript that have the declared but not initialized have the value undefined.
With the `===` operator you make JavaScript check the type and the values you are comparing. If you only use the `==` operator JavaScript will attempt to type convert your variables making this:

```
if (allowedExtensionsUploader == null)
```

into this:

```
if (false == false)
```

which can lead to problems.

Secondly you only provide three arguments to your function but you're asking about the fourth.

Thirdly, the fourth argument is called **allowedExtensions** but you are checking a variable called **allowedExtensionsUploader**.

Fourthly, I think you should use [jslint](http://jslint.com) to check your code. It would have told you a lot of what I just wrote =)

Comment: Actually I use [http://coffeescript.org/] and this is the javascript code that generates this tool when I use something like: `window.SetUploader = (action  = "/Upload", elementID = "file-uploader", multiple = false, allowedExtensions = []) -> //code `

Comment: See this tool running online: http://js2coffee.org/ Copy and paste the  code in tab Coffee -> JS: CODE: `window.SetUploader = (action = "/Upload", elementID = "file-uploader", multiple = false, allowedExtensions = []) -> ### code ###`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing it as the parameter `multiple`, as it is the **third parameter**.

**In JavaScript you cannot have named parameters.**

```
 { allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip'] }
```

Is an object that has a property `allowedExtensions` init to an array.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your arguments do not match your variables in your if statements.
2. You should check whether the variables are `undefined`, not `null`.
3. You should use `===`, not `==`.

Use this instead:

```
window.SetUploader = function(actionUploader, elementIDUploader, multipleUploader, allowedExtensionsUploader) {
    //Optional arguments
    if (actionUploader === undefined) {
      actionUploader = "/Upload";
    }
    if (elementIDUploader === undefined) {
      elementIDUploader = "file-uploader";
    }
    if (multipleUploader === undefined) {
      multipleUploader = false;
    }
    if (allowedExtensionsUploader === undefined) {
      allowedExtensionsUploader = [];
    }
};

SetUploader('/Projects/ImageUpload', 'Logo', undefined, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip']);
```

Comment: Sorry, the parameter name was correct. By moving to the stackoverflow, I wrote wrong.
About null and ==, I use coffee-script, and this was the code it generated.

Even fixing the variable name `allowedExtensions` (see edit), I do not know how to call this function passing only the first two and the last parameter

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa - Just pass in `undefined` (or `null`, if you're checking against that). I just updated my answer, see the last line.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing only three arguments in the function call

the parameter

```
{ allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'zip'] }
```

is a JSON object that will be available in "multiple" variable

Try adding one more argument in the function call, you will get that value as the 4th parameter "allowedExtensions"